# Adding Shared Project gives me error: Multiple shared folders are not supported

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to add a shared project I am receiving the following error:

[image: Error]

I have been trying to fix it for a while and could not find the cause.

Anyone can help me, please?

This error occurs in VS 2019 and 2022.

Comment: Does this happen upon adding the shared project to a solution or adding a reference to that shared project?

Comment: @Beltway When I try to add a reference shows me this error.